# Newly added Column can't be updated even in pgadmin

Tags: sql, postgresql

When i do:

```
 select * from realtimes   where realtime_id = 538189069
```

i can see my columns is_limitation_zone_overspeed and zone_speed_limit

[image]

but when I update it

```
update realtimes 
   set is_limitation_zone_overspeed = true and zone_speed_limit = 90 
where realtime_id = 538189069
```

these field are not affected despite pgadmin
return Query returned successfully: 1 row affected, 181 ms execution time

any idea ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is_limitation_zone_overspeed = true and zone_speed_limit = 90` only updates a **single** column and that is: `is_limitation_zone_overspeed`.

And that column is updated with the result of the boolean expression:

```
true and zone_speed_limit = 90
```

To update **two** columns you need a comma:

```
update realtimes 
   set is_limitation_zone_overspeed = true, --<< here!
       zone_speed_limit = 90 
where realtime_id = 538189069
```

---

You might want to go through the SQL tutorial in the manual:

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-update.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dml-update.html